# How to return a value to an outer Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I'm new to Javascript and learning some basics. Below is my code:

```
test({FirstName: "Codi",LastName: "Madison"}, function (reply) {alert(reply)});

function test(message) {

    return "Hello " + message.FirstName + ' ' + message.LastName

}
```

I want to keep the function(reply) but how do I return a value to it?
I have tried return but the alertbox doesn't fire, what am I missing. Sorry if this is stupid but I'm still learning. Thank you.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/umhxhda2/1/ - change `test` to accept a second parameter - the callback function

Comment: Don't use callback functions if you don't need them.

Comment: @Bergi thats a bit of an odd comment. Why would you use something you don't need. The fact that this user asked this question kind of implies that they *do* need them.

Comment: @Jamiec: He said he's just learning basics, so I'm not sure (and people do lots of weird stuff when they don't entirely understand it). And in the example he's shown, he definitely does *not* need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your function would need to change to include the 2nd parameter and execute that function passing in the *hello* message:

```
function test(message, callback) {
    callback("Hello " + message.FirstName + ' ' + message.LastName);
}
```